# nginx how to access variables from one module from another module?

Tags: c, nginx

There are 2 self-written nginx modules, a data output module and a module that contains actual data. It is necessary initialize the pointer that is located in the output module from the module that contains the actual data. Initialize this pointer with the address to a variable with actual data (which periodically changes its value), so at the time of data output, dereferencing the pointer, show (output) actual data.

Answer (score 1):

use [`ngx_http_add_variable`](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/extending/api/variables/#ngx-http-add-variable) to create the "shared" variable, which should return a `ngx_http_variable_t` which has `ngx_http_set_variable_pt` and `ngx_http_get_variable_pt` function pointer to set a value.

The second module should use [`ngx_http_get_variable`](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/extending/api/variables/#ngx-http-get-variable) to retreive the variable and use the respective `ngx_http_set_variable_pt` and `ngx_http_get_variable_pt`

please refer to the [njs sources](https://github.com/nginx/njs/blob/master/nginx/ngx_http_js_module.c) at the following [position for adding a variable](https://github.com/nginx/njs/blob/master/nginx/ngx_http_js_module.c#L3275) and [for getting a variable](https://github.com/nginx/njs/blob/master/nginx/ngx_http_js_module.c#L2290) for examples

Comment: Thank you for your answer, will try it